# Does the sequence converge?

Tags: analysis

Using the analysis concepts of convergence of sequences, can any one solve the following for  me:

The sequence of real numbers $a_n$ is defined by $a_n=(\root n\of e-1)\cdot n$.
Does the sequence converge? If so, compute its limit.

Thank you.

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: What do you know? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

An idea: put $\,m:=\frac{1}{n}\,$ , so $\,n\to\infty\implies m\to 0^+\,$ :

$$n(e^{1/n}-1) \to \frac{1}{m}(e^m-1)$$

and now take the *function* $\,\frac{1}{x}(e^x-1)\,$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^x-1}{x}$$

Do you now recognize the above limit?

Comment: +1 probably a better solution than mine :P (though 10 bucks says he doesn't know that limit)

Comment: Your solution leads to a rather unpleasant limit of the form $\,\frac{0}{0}\,$ which can be as dense as the original one, imo.

Comment: ah **** why did I think it was right when i first wrote it down? :S

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** for each $n$
$$
\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^n=e
$$